# I'm new to react.js and ran into a problem while working on a project

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a project where I'm required to implement a delete and update button using react.js, can you please assit me and corect me where I may be wrong, thank you.

```
const deleteAdmin = (id) => { 

  const confirm = window.confirm(
    "Are you sure you want to delete this user?"
  );
  if (confirm === true) { 
    Axios.get("https://mindsinaction.com.na/api/delete.php?admin_id=" + id + "&delete_type=user")
      .then((response) => {
        switch (response.data.message) {
          case "success":
            notify("Successfully deleted!");
            // console.log("success.message")
            // This is what I added
            // localStorage.removeItem(id);
            setTimeout(() => this.clear(), 1000);
            setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(true), 1000);
            break;
          case "error":
            errorNotify("Failed to delete product");
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      })

 

<td className="buttons"> 
<button
                        className="delete"
                        onClick={() => deleteAdmin(x.id)}
                      >
                        <RiDeleteBin5Line />
                      </button>
</td>
);
  }else{
    return <Redirect to="/"/>
  }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. The best way is to just put triple backticks before and after a block of code rather than single backticks around each line.

Comment: With that said. What is your question? What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the sections titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem" and "Help others reproduce the problem".

Answer (score 0):

Since you've not share your complete code, it is hard to detect your fault but as I understand you are trying to define the deleteAdmin function in the returned jsx element.

As I understand the button only will be shown when user confirmed the dialog. You can use useState hook in [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

But you should define deleteAdmin function on the outside of returned jsx element like below. And all elements that will display on the screen should be returned.
(Note : I didn't run the code but as I guess it should work)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function yourComponentName() {
    const [isConfirmed,setIsConfirmed] = useState(true)
    const deleteAdmin = (id) => {
        const confirm = window.confirm(
            "Are you sure you want to delete this user?"
        );
        if (confirm === true) {
            Axios.get("https://mindsinaction.com.na/api/delete.php?admin_id=" + id + "&delete_type=user")
                .then((response) => {
                    switch (response.data.message) {
                        case "success":
                            notify("Successfully deleted!");
                            // console.log("success.message")
                            // This is what I added
                            // localStorage.removeItem(id);
                            setTimeout(() => this.clear(), 1000);
                            setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(true), 1000);

                            break;
                        case "error":
                            errorNotify("Failed to delete product");
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                })

        }else{

            setIsConfirmed(false)

        }


    }



    return <>
        {
            isConfirmed?
            <button onClick={()=>deleteAdmin(x.id)}></button>
            :
            <Redirect to="/" />
        }
        </>;
}
```